# Keyboard and mouse stopped working after reboot on Xubuntu 18

Tags: input-devices

My keyboard and mouse stopped working after a reboot of Xubuntu 18x64. Recent changes : installed VirtualBox

Most recent log entries (only show non empty logs after last reboot)

Kern.log
https://www.pastiebin.com/5b353d5864492

sys.log
https://www.pastiebin.com/5b353d926b7f2

xOrg
https://www.pastiebin.com/5b353e43d6033

sysLog
https://www.pastiebin.com/5b353ea29bf7c

lightdm_xorg
https://www.pastiebin.com/5b353f675a5a2

seat0-greeter.log
https://www.pastiebin.com/5b353fbc93080

access_log
https://www.pastiebin.com/5b354023d07d8

lightdm_log
https://www.pastiebin.com/5b353ff528ee5

What could have caused it?